# Why some iPhone devices compile javascript new Date() differently?

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, date

Today I noticed such a weird difference of `new Date()` on iPhone6. On javascript I have a date in terms of ISOString : `"2021-01-19T13:30:00"`.If I put this string inside `new Date("2021-01-19T13:30:00")` here what it gives me : `Tue Jan 19 2021 13:30:00 GMT+0300 (+03)` .I live in `GMT+3` so this is what I expect.(This behavior tested on Windows Google Chrome,Mac Google Chrome,Mac Safari,Iphone X,Iphone,8)

But on iPhone 6 it shows me like that after `new Date("2021-01-19T13:30:00")` (taken from safari web inspector console through iPhone 6)

```
Tue Jan 19 2021 16:30:00 GMT+0300 (+03).
```

Why this difference occurs and how can I convert this date as same as all other devices do?If you have iPhone 6 device you can try in the way I did or try to run iPhone 6 simulator.IOS version of mine is : 13.1.3
All devices I've tested have same date and location

Comment: Doesn't sound right -- but perhaps if you are explicit about it (add `Z` at the end) the bug will disappear.

Comment: IPhone 6 is wrong here - [the specs for parsing this string](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-date.parse) specify that a date-time string without a timezone offset is interpreted as local time. By contrast a *date* string is interpreted as UTC. So `2021-01-19` is interpreted as if "2021-01-19T00:00:00Z" while `2021-01-19T00:00:00` (no offset at the end) is interpreted as if "2021-01-19T00:00:00+03:00".

Comment: So how to fix this problem and make iPhone 6 correct?I tried adding Z in the end for iphone6 but it messed the result for other devices

Comment: Adding `Z` to the end *should* make the date interpretation the same on all devices. From what you've described here, I'd expect iPhone to maintain the same date, however, all others environments which are spec compliant will change. This is because with a `Z` the date will be interpreted as UTC, so `13:30Z` is 15:30 local time. If you're operating within the same time zone, then you can use the time zone's offset `13:30+03:00`. However, beware that hardcoding the offset will be incorrect accros time zones and even daylight savings. Using a library to parse it might be the simplest way.